# Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using Gradle

Tags: eclipse, spring, gradle, eclipse-plugin, gradle-eclipse

I have a gradle project which is configured and working fine in Windows environment but the same is not working when I try and run it in Mac.

Project and Environment Configuration:

> Gradle 2.5/2.6
>   Eclipse Luna/Mars
>   Gradle Project using SpringBoot

The gradle project is checked out from the SVN but when I run the project as Gradle project it gives me the below error:

> Configuration with name 'default' not found.
>   Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using Gradle installation '/Users/vips/Documents/Software/gradle-2.6'.

I have downloaded and configured Gradle 2.5 and 2.6 both but I get the same error.

Again: It works fine in Windows 7, but not in Mac.

Any help here is much appreciated.

**Additional Information:**
I noticed that the above issue comes only for a project that is dependent on another project. For an independent gradle project, this just works fine. All dependencies are loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. In my case, somehow one of the dependent project was not checked out correctly.

I deleted that project and did a fresh checkout from SVN and it worked.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly the reason why it happens is because new version of gradle has to be downloaded. Once you download new version of gradle, your error will go away.

http://gradle.org/downloads

Comment: Like I said, I tried with version 2.5 and 2.6 both. Nothing works on Mac. But works perfectly fine in Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

This "could not fetch model of type..." error can be caused by a syntax error in the build.gradle file. If so, the error has nothing to do with the Gradle or Eclipse version you are running.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33632014/gradle-gets-unexpected-token-compile-files)

Answer (score -2):

It can be due to Internet connectivity while trying to connect to repository.